# Google colab errors - Notebook loading error:

Tags: google-colaboratory

When I open in Google Drive an error appears:

```
There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.
A network error occurred and the request could not be completed.

https://drive.google.com/drive/?action=locate&id=1HokQj5jSvoeblc3dOr4A_iLnDGN377dZ&authuser=1

Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

When I try to download via colab.research.google.com, an error appears:

```
A network error occurred and the request could not be completed.
GapiError: A network error occurred and the request could not be completed.
at GG.hy [as constructor] (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:1345:363)
    at new GG (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:1564:363)
    at za.program_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:1652:331)
    at Ba (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:509:336)
    at za.throw_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:508:402)
    at Da.throw (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:510:248)
    at c (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20190311-085300-RC00_237811388:519:79)
```

At the same time, the examples provided by Colab, for example, colab.research.google.com/notebooks/bigquery.ipynb are working fine.

Comment: What errors are reported for the fetch in the [Chrome network console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/resource-loading#view_details_for_a_single_resource)?

Answer (score 1):

consider **restarting your browser**.

I get a similar problem using colab with firefox sometimes.   Same initial message:
There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again. A network error occurred and the request could not be completed.

Then colab gets stuck, and won't open any files at all.   Closing and restarting the colab tab does not clear the problem.

Eventually I discovered that restarting firefox fixes it for me.

I realise that this is too late to help the OP, and it may not be quite the same problem anyway, but when I first hit the issue myself I couldn't find any online help for it, so now I've got an answer I wanted to share.

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar problem using colab with any app and used a vpn proxy and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the cookies and refresh the tab, it worked for me.